# How to write a custom ScrollView in xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio, xamarin.forms

Am new to xamarin technology. I am more of a WPF developer. I wish to develope an application in xamarin that displays data in a table format. Am developing the application in cross platforms which should be running in **xamarin.forms, xamarin.Android and xamarin.IOS**. The problem am facing is to write a **scrollViewer in common** for all the platforms. **Is there any workaround to write a custom scroll viewer(with both Horizontal and Vertical scrolling) that works in common for the three platforms?** It would be ***helpful if I could be pointed to some blogs or links*** defining this.

Comment: What are the actual requirements of the scroll view? Have you used the Xamarin.Forms scroll view or list view?

Comment: I need both horizontal and vertical scrolling. The default scroll view supports only one scrolling.

Comment: I am facing the same issue with Xamarin.Forms. If I add scrollview in my Xaml page then when I focus on any textbox then entire page gets scrolled up and can't see anything on screen.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question well, your problem is that Xamarin.Forms.ScrollView can scroll only horizontally or vertically.

so you can make a scrollview inside another scroll view one is horizontal and the other is vertical.

Like that

```
ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView{
    Orientation=ScrollOrientation.Vertical,
    Content = new ScrollView{
        Orientation=ScrollOrientation.Horizontal,
        Content = new StackLayout{
            Children={new Label{Text="some text"}}
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems, as you are searching for a Grid...?
Maybe you should have a look and the component store:

[free Grid-control from DevExpress](https://components.xamarin.com/view/devexpress-grid)

Note: There also are some other Grid-components in the store (but not for free:-)